# FORX0003: The regular expression in tokenize() must not be one that matches a zero-length string

Tags: xslt

Hi this is working for "," and other delimiters but it's not working for PIPE(|) symbol only it's giving FORX0003: The regular expression in tokenize() must not be one that matches a zero-length string

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="text/text()" name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,$separator)">
        <item>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you please phrase your question in a clearer manner?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that, uhh, the regular expression in tokenize() must not be one that matches a zero-length string. How does "'|'" match a zero-length string? Because it is an alternative between two zero-length strings.

Answer (score 10):

You just need to replace `<xsl:param name="separator" select="'|'"/>` to  `<xsl:param name="separator" select="'\|'"/>` if you want to tokenize from '|' character. Have a look my sample XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="text">Navin | Rawat</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="separator" select="'\|'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($text,$separator)">
    <item>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </item>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<item>Navin</item><item>Rawat</item>
```